How to stop Visual Studio Code (vs-code) from automatically creating solution (.sln) files
Some users may face following exception if they don't un-check this option in their recent versions (1.90+) of vs-code:

error MSB1011: Specify which project or solution file to use because this folder contains more than one project or solution file.


If you are looking for "Visual Studio" which is different to "Visual Studio Code", this may come handy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452135

In addition to Tayyebi's answer, you could set it in the Workspace settings instead of the User settings. The change will then be saved in the .vscode/settings.json. This allows you to check it into git so it will apply the change to all users of the repo.

To stop Visual Studio Code (vs-code) to auto generate .sln files, you can edit it from vscode-insiders://settings/dotnet.automaticallyCreateSolutionInWorkspace.


related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/395, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/357
